# Can I use a EF lens on my Canon 7D camera?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, tamron, third-party

I have a Canon 7D (EF-S) and was thinking of buying a Tamron SP 24-70mm f/2.8 Di VC USD G2 lens (model number AO32) for the Canon EF mount.

Will this lens be ok for my camera?

Comment: Related to https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/can-i-use-a-ef-lens-with-a-ef-s-camera?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Canon's EF-S bodies also accept EF lenses.